# What's a politically neutral word for having only one permitted set of beliefs?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word where people are critical of an opposing idea, usually without examining it, simply because it's different from what people already believe.

I thought that *fascist* (of or relating to fascism) was the word I was looking for, but Wiktionary defines [*fascism*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fascism) as:

> ### Noun
>
> **fascism** (*usually uncountable, plural* **fascisms**)
>
> 1. Any right-wing, authoritarian, nationalist ideology characterized by centralized, totalitarian governance, strong regimentation of the economy and of society, and repression of criticism or opposition.

The only part of the meaning I want is "repression of criticism or opposition", without the political implications of the remainder of the meaning.

> To refuse to admit the possibility that contrary ideas could be valid is ___.
>
> The oppression of people who believe differently is ___.

It doesn't necessarily have to be an adjective; a noun would probably be workable too.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing "reactionary", though the term has several secondary connotations.

Comment: Maybe an "ideologue".

Comment: I would use fascist, for that.

Comment: In some sentences, *party line* would work, e.g. *It's hard to build consensus in the current climate of party line politics, He resigned because he didn't want to be boxed into party line politics, X is a party line politician*; also consider *dogma, dogmatic, partisan*.

Comment: Would people please stop answering in comments? It bypasses the quality control.

Comment: We're getting all the synonyms of 'close-minded', 'bigot/ry'. As has happened too frequently.  Are you looking for a more political term?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

[closed-minded](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/closed-minded)

> not willing to consider different ideas or opinions : having or showing a closed mind

Comment: ... and *closed-mindedness* for the other example sentence.